# Using "read" from a called shell script (Mac Terminal)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, installation

I'm currently building an unattended install script for a mac based environment.

For that I have a series of applications as PKG's + a lot of other settings and plist configurations that I'm installing/copying. If I put them all in one bash script, it all lines work as expected. Now I'm cleaning up and separating the different tasks (installing applications, installing printers, network preferences etc.) in separate bash scripts to maybe also use them separately at some other point.

I now have a set of files e.g:

1. install.sh
2. install_printers.sh

However, some of these scripts are requiring user input (e.g. question whether or not a specific printer shall be installed).

This looks as follows:

**install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo 1 | sudo -S sh /Volumes/install/install_printers.sh
```

**install_printers.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo    
echo "Install: DE_Brother [y/n]"
read -n 1 question
if [ "$question" = "y" ]
then
    echo
    lpadmin -p DE_Brother -L "DE" -E -v ipp://10.1.1.100:631/printers/PM_Brother -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/Brother.gz -o printer-is-shared=false
    cp /Volumes/install/Plist\ files/com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.DE-Brother.plist ~/Library/Preferences/
    echo "DE_Brother is installed"
else
    echo
    echo "DE_Brother not installed"
fi
echo    
echo "Install: DE_Brother2 [y/n]"
read -n 1 question
if [ "$question" = "y" ]
then
    echo
    lpadmin -p DE_Brother2 -L "DE" -E -v ipp://10.1.1.100:631/printers/PM_Brother -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/Brother2.gz -o printer-is-shared=false
    cp /Volumes/install/Plist\ files/com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.DE_Brother2.plist ~/Library/Preferences/
    echo "DE_Brother is installed"
else
    echo
    echo "DE_Brother not installed"
fi
```

Right now, when I run the above "install.sh", I will always get the "else" of the if statement. Obviously because the script continues without the requested user input *read -n 1 question*.

So how will I be able to ask for user input in a called script?

I'm pretty new to that topic, so if there are other suggestions/improvements, please let me know

cheers
Julian

Comment: If the scripts are meant to run unattended, it would be simpler to use command line arguments rather than standard input to pass options into each script.

Comment: I don't understand your question.
When I run this (leaving out the install commands) it asks me for y/n. If I type y, "Installed" appears like you would want...

Comment: Maybe the user is typing "Y" instead of "y"?  It might be worth adding an "or" (`-o` using the old-style test command, or use `||` with `[[   ]]`).